# Jaspert report prevent last page only display last page footer band/part of summary band

Tags: jasper-reports, page-break

I am using iReport 3.7.4, the problem now occurs is:

in some cases, the summary's detail overflow and start a new page without background band, this is ugly and not acceptable by the client.

So, i try to solve the problem by putting the summary band's items to last page footer but only last page foot displayed with no background bank again in some other cases.

What can i do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The band's background is must to the same report the band height size. After increasing the height size of the band's background should adjust the image size.